# Django, generic view dynamic filtering

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-generic-views

i'm starting out with Django and trying to render all Shows(screenings) that selected Movie had. Here's the code:

**url**

`path('movie/<int:pk>/', MovieDetails.as_view(), name='movie'),`

**Models**

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.title}'

class Show(models.Model):
    show_date = models.DateField()
    start_time = models.TimeField()
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.show_date}'
```

**View**

```
class MovieDetails(DetailView):
    model = Movie
    context_object_name = 'movie'

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.movie = get_object_or_404(Movie, id=self.kwargs['pk']) #find movie by id from url
        shows_played = Show.objects.filter(movie=self.movie)
        print(shows_played) #prints out some shows
        return shows_played

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['shows_played'] = Show.objects.filter(movie=self.movie)

        return context
```

The shows_played prints out some shows, so it seems like everything is fine but when the url: /movies/1
is called I get a 404, No show found matching the query rendered in browser and
`Not Found: /movie/1/` printed in console

What am i doing wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My mistake was that i was using DetailView instead of ListView(which has get_queryset method) for "MovieDetails".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).